# VB.NET Assign a hotkey or use enter to insert a record

Tags: listview, keyboard-shortcuts, vb.net-2010, enter

I would like to use a listview for data entry purposes. I have several dropdowns, checkboxes and textboxes in the listview. As the end-user navigates through the grid, at any given time, the end-user wants to be able to click either enter, or a specific hot key, which would trigger a link button click event to insert the record.
Is this possible in VB.Net Web Application? It is not a form, nor is it a Windows App. I would like to use this js function

```
function KeysShortcut() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentMain_ lvIncExpTrans").onsubmit();

    }
}
```

from this link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LbtnInsert"  TabIndex="30" runat="server"
 CssClass="highlightInsert" Width="60px" Height="50px" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"
 OnClick="LbtnInsert_Click" />
```

to fire this sub Protected Sub `lvIncExpTrans_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As ListViewInsertEventArgs)` Handles lvIncExpTrans.ItemInserting

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Can you show us some code or explain a bit more about what you've tried?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gray, I want to use this script  document.attachEvent('onkeyup', KeysShortcut);        
           function KeysShortcut() {

               if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                   document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentMain_ lvIncExpTrans").onsubmit();

               }

           } to fire this link button in a listview <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LbtnInsert"  TabIndex="30" runat="server" CssClass="highlightInsert" Width="60px" Height="50px" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" OnClick="LbtnInsert_Click" /></td>

Comment: and trigger this sub routine   Protected Sub lvIncExpTrans_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles lvIncExpTrans.ItemInserting

Comment: I don't know if you can read that (My post). I am trying to use JS, to trigger a sub routine when pressing enter. Right now, the LBTNInsert_Click does nothing. I did try to call the sub for inserting from this Sub (LBTN_Insert)